# Not able to execute selenium test scripts more than 30 minutes using MS Test with C#

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, mstest

My test case is getting aborted while executing the selenium test script using MS Test.
This execution will take more than 30 minutes. Is there any time related dependency in MSTest or else it requires any settings?

Can somebody provide solution for the above issue?

Answer (score 0):

Default execution timeout for mstest is 30 minutes. If your test case takes more than 30 minutes to execute, use below attribute in your mstest test case:

```
[Timeout(TestTimeout.Infinite)]
```

If you want, you can provide a definite timeout instead of infinite.